# Log4j JDBCAppender with customized column value

Tags: java, log4j

I'm building a data analysis web application in Java. For every day, I get data from other companies' projects and do some process. I identify each project by **unique pid**. The issue when I try to use log4j to insert rows to DB like:

```
INSERT INTO app_log(pid, date, level, class, message)
```

I can only get the **pid** during runtime, and my processing is in multithread. If I set the SQL clause programmatically like:

```
props.put("log4j.appender.DB.sql", "INSERT INTO app_log(pid, date, level, class, message) VALUES('" + productId + "','%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}', '%p', '%c', '%m')");
```

Will the **pid1** logs be misset to **pid2** since they are running at the same time?

What I really want to achieve is to store different logs into DB according to their own **pid**.

Could you offer me any good solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like MDC and ThreadContext will mess the **pid**, so I find it better to implement my own DB Logger with my application.